# ECMA Script 6 Arrow functions as object properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I realise this is a pointless thing to do but I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
var person = {
    _name: "Steve",
    doSomething: () => console.debug("Doing stuff with ", this._name)
}
```

"this" is bound to the global object and not the object getName was invoked on. I was expecting that the above is equivalent to :

```
var person = {
    _name: "Steve",
    doSomething: function() { console.debug("Doing stuff with ", this._name) }
}
```

(I know you should write it like this)

```
var person = {
   _name: "Steve",
   doSomething() {
      console.debug("Doing stuff with ", this._name)
   }
}
```

Comment: "I know you should write it like this" - No, you should not.

Comment: Strange: In Chrome Version 38.0.2125.104 (64-bit), `this` still refers the `window` object.

Comment: @thefourtheye sure you're calling it like `person.getName()`?

Comment: @thefourtheye I cannot think why you say you should not use that style - perhaps I confused the issue by using a get function, suppose the function does something other that simply return a value.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: And I guess, the equivalent would rather be `function() { return console.debug("Doing stuff with ", this._name) }`

Comment: Yes - you're quite right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this):

> Arrow functions capture the this value of the enclosing context

This is different to functions.

Comment: @RahilWazir Oh, I didn't see the `class`, I thought that it is a function.

Comment: btw - it is valid syntax see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: @Woody Hmm I thought that part got nuked from ES6, it was probably something else, I've removed that part from my answer.